# I want to change the css of a div on home page only but it should remain unchanged on other routes in opencart. Can anyone have an idea?

Tags: css, opencart, stylesheet

I have categories showing on home page just below the slider, I want to align it just aside the slider instead below it. I think that can be done by giving some negative top margin to that div. But problem is how can I do css for only home page not for other pages

Here is the link to that page which I want to change.

http://kiranalala.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer and it was quite simpler than i thought. Doing some CSS work as needed and preparing the required class,I used the php $_SERVER function to get over with the url problem.

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/')?>
   {
     echo $class ="the_class_needed_to_align_div";
   }
   else{
       echo $clasas = "default_class";
   }
```

And then called $class variable in the div which needed to be realigned.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know about opencart but CSS.

I assume you've the same site structure as this :http://demo.opencart.com/

So what you can do is use homepage class as a parent class for your requirement.

[image]

Like in above image we can use "common-home" as parent class so that will affect only for home page.

So your code can be like as following

```
.common-home .home-slide{
    margin-top:-15px
}
```

You should put some of your source code to give us a perfect solution.

Comment: Referring to your image, lets assume I want to change the css of class="col-sm-4".

Comment: Yes so you can write code as following -  

.common-home .col-sm-4{
    margin-top:-15px
}  

And this will affect only for your homepage.

Comment: Well if you have not created any custom .css file for writing your custom css then please make one. or else As per demo link I suggest you should append code in this file http://demo.opencart.com/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css at the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to move your whole id="column-left" div to inside of span12 div as shown in image.